# Writing in a newly created Google spreadsheet using an external script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I have built a short script that takes inputs from a Google Form and creates a new spreadsheet. But when I try to set that values inside the sheet, nothing happens. Not sure if this is due to my code or to the lack of authorization given this is a newly created file. Here is my code:

```
  var templates = DriveApp.getFilesByName('Template'); // get the files named Template (only one)
  var template = templates.next(); // get the first files in the list
  var newFile = template.makeCopy(name,newFolder); // Make a copy of the Template file and put it in NewFolder
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.open(newFile);
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  sheet.getActiveRange('B1').setValue(name);
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

I think that in your script, an error occurs at `getActiveRange('B1')`. Because the method `getActiveRange()` of Class Sheet has not arguments. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getactiverange) I think that this is the reason of your issue. In this case, an error like `The parameters (String) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getActiveRange.` occurs. I thought that the reason of `nothing happens` might be that from your question, the script is run by the OnSubmit event trigger might be used. In this case, please modify as follows.

#### From:

```
sheet.getActiveRange('B1').setValue(name);
```

#### To:

```
sheet.getRange('B1').setValue(name);
```

- When you modify like above and run again, the value of `name` is put to the cell "B2" on the 1st tab in the created Spreadsheet.

#### Note:

- If you want to append the values when the script is run, please modify `sheet.getActiveRange('B1').setValue(name);` as follows.

  ```
    sheet.appendRow([, name]);  // In this case, the value is append to the column "B".
  ```

#### References:

- [getActiveRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getactiverange)
- [getRange(a1Notation)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(String))